How can I access the native HTML5 Blob in WordPress?
I am trying to convert a recording captured with MediaRecorder from WebM to WAV.
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream); // stream passed from navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia
let chunks = [];

mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(event) {
  if (event.data.size > 0) {
    chunks.push(event.data);
  }
};

mediaRecorder.onstop = function() {
  const wavBlob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });
};

When the media recorder stops, the console outputs the following error:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'arrayBuffer' on 'Blob': Illegal invocation

window.Blob produces the same error.
I believe this is because Blob is being overwritten with the Blob class from wp-includes/js/plupload/moxie.js (Line 3421). This Blob does not work the same as the HTML5 Blob and I do not see a way to access the HTML5 Blob from it.
I tried saving a reference to the HTML5 Blob on page load like so:
<head>
  <script>const htmlBlob = Blob;</script>
</head>

However, new htmlBlob creates a plupload Blob and causes the same console error.
I assume moxie.js is required for WordPress to run properly, so unqueuing it does not seem like a good solution.
I also tried setting the mimeType to WAV when constructing the MediaRecorder:
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: 'audio/wav' });

This produces the following console error:

NotSupportedError: Failed to construct 'MediaRecorder': Failed to initialize native MediaRecorder the type provided (audio/wav) is not supported.


what's the context for this? Frontend? Admin settings page? Editor screen? Also how did you confirm/identify that this specific Blob was overwriting it?

I suspect that Blob has not been replaced, a quick check on the media upload page shows it as "native code", whereas window.moxie.file.Blob exists as does window.m0xie.Blob, I see no evidence of the plupload moxie library overwriting window.Blob, chrome reports it as ƒ Blob() { [native code] }

I'm using this on the frontend. My IDE identifies Blob as the moxie Blob, Ctrl+clicking it opens moxie.js at line 3421. Is this just an IDE error then?

I confirmed this was an issue with my IDE. After excluding the plupload directory, the Blob warning went away and Blob now correctly identifies as an HTML5 Blob. The illegal invocation error I assumed was caused by this is actually caused by something else.
